# Leading coefficient of a polynomial quotient is equal

Tags: calculus, limits, polynomials

Isn't there something special that you can infer when a polynomial's leading coefficients are equal on the numerator and denominator, like this:

$\frac{x^4}{x^4+3x^4}$

I'm trying to find the limit of the function at (0,0) of $\frac{x^2y^2}{x^4+3y^4}$ and I'm approaching the function when y=x.

Thanks guys.

Comment: You mean the limit at $(0,0)$, right?

Comment: Yeah I'll add that above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that you can combine the terms in the denominator, then simplify the whole thing into a single term after that.

Comment: Wow, I'm up way too late. Thanks man!